# Mysql says unique error where there is no unique value in table

Tags: mysql

This is the error message i get from my codeignitor site...

```
Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'asset_barcode'

INSERT INTO `assets` (`asset_barcode`, `asset_type`, `status`) VALUES ('4661957312', 'HARDWARE', 1)

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

In this asset_barcode is a unique number generated by rand() function of PHP. This error is coming eventhough there is no data in database on that field. also the query 'asset_barcode' is different from the mysql error message barcode !! unabel to figure out the issue !

This is my table description:

[table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDfsN.png)

Comment: what is your database schema? What data is in the table? We need a [mcve]

Comment: Is asset_barcode a float data type by any chance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE assets` and to  show us a few lines of sample data from that table..

Comment: this is how my database looks...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDfsN.png

Comment: @ P.Salmon - No it is a int(11) field...

Comment: Max int size is 4294967295

Comment: oh let me change it to double and see if that helps

Comment: You might be better with bigint https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html